# How can I trigger a Bootstrap popover when clicking an external SVG path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I have a HTML page with an external svg included in an Object Tag like this.

```html
<object data="test1.svg" id="svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="img-responsive" viewBox="0 0 60 55"></object>
```

I want to be able to click on an svg path to open a Bootstrap Popover above the svg at the position where I clicked.
I've been trying something like this:

```js
document.getElementById("svg").addEventListener("load", function() {
var doc = this.getSVGDocument();
   doc.getElementById("path88").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      $("#svg").contents().find("#path88").popover({title: "Header", content: "Blabla", placement: "top", trigger: "click"});
   });
});
```

But I couldn't get it to work. I know that it is possible to include Javascript in the svg file but I want to trigger the Popover dierectly over Javascript(or Jquery) in my main page. How can I do this? Please help

Comment: `doc.getElementById()` is wrong - you have to pass an id like `doc.getElementById('svg')`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the id while posting. The Id is generated dynamicly in my script but I didn't want to post my whole script. Corrected now.